# not showing uuid in production log

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Please help me with this:

```
config.log_tags = [:uuid]
```

I have written it in config.rb(development), and it worked

but in my config/production.rb it is not working

I found reason is this line:

```
config.logger = ::Logger.new(config.paths['log'].first, 3000, 1000.megabytes)
```

when I romve the last line it works

can anyone tell me what is the issue